# "Dictionary update sequence element #0 has lenght"

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

ошибка `dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 12; 2 is required`
Надо было получить текст из запроса `requests.get("https://www.google.com/")`, и из ссылок полученных при помощи regex отделить ссылки, и посчитать сколько раз встречается определенное слово в `result`. Возможно, я совершенно неправильно сделал задачу, и ошибка исходит отсюда, в любом случае прошу помощи в решении этого вопроса. Код:

```
import requests, re

response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")

result = re.findall(r'/[A-Za-z\.]+/', response.text)
print(result)

def count_words(List):
    counter = 0
    for word in range(len(List)):
        if List.has_key(word):
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 0        
    print(f"word {word} matches {counter}")

count_words(dict(result))
```

Comment: Подсчет проще делать через `Counter`, добавил пример в ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests, re

response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")

result = re.findall(r'/[A-Za-z\.]+/', response.text)

def count_words(List):
    Dict = {}
    for word in List:
        if word in Dict:
            Dict[word] += 1
        else:
            Dict[word] = 1
            
    for word, counter in Dict.items():
        print(f"word {word} matches {counter}")

count_words(result)
```

Comment: Лучше не называть переменные в верхнем регистре и разделять импорт стандартных библиотек и устанавливаемых

Answer (score 3):

Подсчет можно сделать проще через `Counter`.

Попробуйте:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

import requests


def count_words(words):
    for word, counter in Counter(words).items():
        print(f"word {word} matches {counter}")


response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")
result = re.findall(r'/[A-Za-z.]+/', response.text)
count_words(result)
```

---

**PS.**

В квадратных скобках регулярки не нужно экранировать метасимволы. Поэтому у меня точка без `\`

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. Экономит место и выглядит проще, однако, было важно что бы было какое то решение. Я пока новичок, не все знаю

Comment: @Lcashe, пожалуйста :)