# No connection adapters were found for

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, requests

Задача заключается в вводе ссылки и далее задача также описана: ["Dictionary update sequence element #0 has lenght"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220870/dictionary-update-sequence-element-0-has-lenght)

Ввожу для теста ссылку `https://stackoverflow.com/`

Сообщение ошибки: No connection adapters were found for "['https://stackoverflow.com/']"

Толком даже не понимаю в чем ошибка, то что находил в интернете не подходит под этот случай.

**File.py:**

```
import re, requests
from collections import Counter

url_input = input("Enter url: ")

url_checked = re.findall(r'https?://\S+', url_input)


if url_input != url_checked:
    print("Entered url is invalid")
else:
    pass

response = requests.get(str(url_checked))
result = re.findall(r'/[A-Za-z.]+/', response.text)

def count_words(List):
    for word, counter in Counter(List).items():
        print(f"{word} matches {counter} times")

count_words(result)
```

Comment: Символы косой черты для обозначения литерала регулярного выражения не используются в Python, в вашем регулярном выражении они являются частью шаблона. Удалите `/` в вашем выражении.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew во второй re.findall(...) все работает как нужно. Проблема заключается не в этом, поскольку ошибка появляется на 14-й строчке - ```response = requests.get(str(url_checked))```

Comment: Тогда зачем вы вообще используете `re.findall`? Вам нужен `re.search`. `m = re.search(..., response.text)` => `if m:`  => `url_checked = m.group()`

Comment: сейчас попробую ваш вариант, с вариантом отмеченным как решение все работает как требуется

Comment: `m = re.search(..., response.text)` => `if m:`  => `url_checked = m.group()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall` возвращает все совпадения. Если будет одно то получится список с одним элементом, поэтому Вам надо взять первый элемент

```
url_checked = re.findall(r'https?://\S+', url_input)[0]
```

Comment: заменить в url_checked?